# How to use styles from separate xaml files

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a styles.xaml file that lists a set of colors. These colors define how certain elements within one part of the application are shown, and thus are used through a converter.

I would like to create a legend of these colors in another part of the application, and have a toggle button list that I'd like to set the background colors to the colors defined in the styles.xaml.

Would I need to somehow include the styles.xaml file into the xaml file defining the toggle buttons? Or is there some way I can bind directly to these color values?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add styles.xaml to App.xaml

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >       
            <ResourceDictionary Source="styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Tried this, but I'm getting the following error:
All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them. styles.xaml only contains a resourceDictionary, and all elements have keys (except for subelements of elements).

Comment: Add keys to the styles in "styles.xaml". Or the "styles.xaml" should be a <ResourceDictionary> as well.

Comment: Yes, you need set x:Key for all your colors in styles.xaml

Comment: For my case, the xaml is a user control, so in <UserControl.Resources> I have a style with a x:Key. Under that style, I have the <ResourceDictionary> and the MergedDictionaries code like shown in the answer above. Is this "legal" or "correct" or maybe why I'm still not able to get this to work?

Comment: @Chris Schaller - Consider posting an answer with the contents of  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9491974. Meta question about your edit here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305966/edit-review-are-extensive-edits-of-accepted-answer-ok

Answer (score 4):

> **Note** Attribution for the following content / answer should go to [@Chris Schaller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690217/chris-schaller). This answer's content was originally posted as an edit to @chameleon86 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14281160/2279200) and was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9491974) (see also [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305966/edit-review-are-extensive-edits-of-accepted-answer-ok) meta). However I think, this is some valuable content and so I am 'reposting' it.

To make the definitions in styles.xaml available to all XAML within the app, add styles.xaml to App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >  
            <ResourceDictionary Source="styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- You can declare additional resources before or after Merged dictionaries, but not both -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DefaultBackgroundColorBrush" Color="Cornsilk" />
        <Style x:Key="DefaultBackgroundColor" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DefaultBackgroundColorBrush}" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

To understand how this works, at runtime your window, page or control will exist as child elements of the running application visual tree.

Your initial question noted:

> "These colors define how certain elements within *one part* of the application..."

If you only need these style resources available to *some* xaml pages or windows, and not all of them, then you can still use this pattern to merge the local resources for a window, or for grids or other controls directly.

- Note that doing this makes these styles only available to child elements of the element that you declared the Resource Dictionary.

See how simple it is scope the style reference to a single grid for usage:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary >
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >       
                <ResourceDictionary Source="styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- You can declare additional resources before or after Merged dictionaries, but not both -->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <!--
        Grid Content :)
      -->
</Grid>
```